# Multidependent picklists salesforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning, configuration

I need to set up a picklist that is dependent on what is selected on two other picklists.

What I need is to set it such that third result depends on first and second choices.

This process should be done while creating or editing a record.

```
Picklist value 1     Picklist value 2

       |                    |

       V                     V

            Picklist value 3
```

Can you suggest any approach to achieve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably not something you want to hear. But multiple controlling fields is not supported by salesforce. You can vote on this idea at: https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Br1aAAC.

A workaround that I can think of would be to create a validation rule that prevents users from creating/saving a record when a certain picklist value is selected on the dependent picklist field based on what the current value is on the controlling picklist fields.